# How to determine selected `configuration` in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-buildconfig

In Android Studio I created two configurations:

[image]

How can I determine in code which configuration I selected?

I know that there is `buildConfigField` in `/app/build.gradle` but the names of the `buildTypes` do not correspond to the `configuration` names, so I wonder how does that all fit together.

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG', 'true'
        }
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that in Android Studio a `configuration` corresponds to a `schema` in Xcode and a `buildConfigField` corresponds to the `Environment Variable` in Xcode (me coming from iOS world).

Comment: "How can I determine in code which configuration I selected?" -- generally, you don't. A run configuration is an IDE thing, not an Android thing. If I had to guess, you are conflating run configurations ("what code or tests am I executing in this IDE?") with build variants (e.g., "is this `debug` or `release`?"). The latter is controlled via the Build Variants window, by default docked on the lower left side of the Android Studio window.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, what I want is to define environment variable values that I can use in code, e.g. in a debug build variant I want to connect to the development database, in a release build variant I want to connect to the production database.

Comment: Have you read the [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) in the Android documentation? It describes how to use flavors which is the common way to switch between productive and dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I determine in code which configuration I selected?

You don't, insofar as a run configuration is an IDE thing, not an Android thing.

> what I want is to define environment variable values that I can use in code, e.g. in a debug build variant I want to connect to the development database, in a release build variant I want to connect to the production database

None of that has anything to do with run configurations. Run configurations are for configuring what is to be run:

- the main `app`
- tests for the main `app`
- tests for the `something` library
- etc.

`debug` versus `release` are build types, one dimension of the build variant. You choose which build variant the run configurations use via the Build Variants tool, docked by default on the lower-left side of the Android Studio IDE window.

To have different code behavior based upon `debug` versus `release`, you can:

- Examine `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE`, which will be either `debug` or `release`
- Use `buildConfigField` to inject values into `BuildConfig` from Gradle, based upon build type and/or product flavor
- Use `resConfig` to inject values into resources, such as string resources
- Use custom source sets per build type (e.g., `src/main/` for your common code, `src/debug/` for debug-specific code, `src/release/` for release-specific code)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure different resource sets. By default `main` and `debug` already exist. To determine at runtime which set was used to build the apk create a new resource file in each resource set, e.g.

`app/src/main/res/values/resourceset.xml`
 and 
`app/src/debug/res/values/resourceset.xml`

and place a single string or integer value inside like this:

```
<resources>
     <string name="resource_set">debug</string>
</resources>
```

and

```
<resources>
     <string name="resource_set">main</string>
</resources>
```

You may then use `getString()` to get the value for `R.string.resource_set` and you can detect which resource set was used.

I am using this technique to include different Google API client IDs depending on the resource set that was used (to enable debugging with Google APIs and release with another fingerprint then debug).